# Recommended way to store data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase

I want to use elasticsearch on my backend and I have few questions:

1. My DB contains semi-structured data of products, i.e. each product may have different attributes inside it. 
   I want to be able to search a text on most of the fields and also search a text on one specific field. 
   What is the recommended way to store the document in ES ? to store all text in on field (maybe using _all feature) or leave it in different fields.
   My concern of different fields is that I might have a lot of indexes (because I have many different product attributes)
2. I'm using couchbase as my main DB. 
   What is the recommended way to move the documents from it to ES, assuming I need to make some modifications on the document ? 
   To update the index from my code explicitly or use external tool ?

10x,

Comment: Please consider splitting up your questions in two posts, you won't not be able to mark several correct answers.

Comment: There is a transport couchbase plugin to ES that replicates data automatically. https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elasticsearch-transport-couchbase

Also listen to @KristapsKarlsons :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many docs you are indexing at a time. If the number of docs are like >2million. Then it's better to store everything in one field , which will save time while indexing.

If the docs indexed are very less, then index them field by field and then search on _all field. This will give a clear view on the data and will be really helpful for what to display and what not to display.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I don't need to index too much at the time, but I have a lot of reads.
But, just to clarify, I want to better understand how it affects ES the document structure...
Does it save each field in different index ?
If yes, then it means that if I have different products with a lot of different attributes, then I will have a lot of indexes (assuming index per field).

Comment: Here an index means a schema or a DB in sql. Type means a table and fields are columns in that table....So, from this each field will not be a different index. What happens is when you index a doc with different fields, the mapping will keep on updating which takes lot of time to index in case of large docs. If the data or docs are less, then that doesn't matter...